# Is it possible to draw the graph of the curve given by hand, $x^5+y^5=5a^2xy^2$ without a calculator/computer?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I came across this question which asks me to draw the graph by hand(just with hand and head) for the following curve:-
$$x^5+y^5=5a^2xy^2$$
Here, I don't think [swapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1691815/how-to-graph-an-implicit-function-by-hand) is going to work out. So here is what I *usually* do while drawing curves.

#**Points of Intersection with the Cordinate Axes**
Here there is only one point that of origin, thus the curves passes through origin.

#**Finding any asymptotes**
Here $x+y=0$ is the only asymptote for the curve

#**Odd/even/Neither Odd nor even function**
Here $x \rightarrow -x, y \rightarrow -y$ Gives us back the original curve thus the curves is symmetrical in opposite quadrants.

#**Monotonicity of intervals**
But here is where my problem arises, I am not able to evaluate the curve’s derivative.

#**Evaluating concavity/convexity**
If I am not able to evaluate the first derivative then I am not going to be able to get till here. Moreover the last two parts are the most crucial and without being able to evaluate them, I will not be able to draw the curve.

So my question is can we find the derivative just in terms of $x$ somehow? If not, then is there some other method to this?

***TL;DR*** Is there any way of drawing the curve $x^5+y^5=5a^2xy^2$ by hand?

Comment: You can get several points by solving $(x,kx)$ for various values of $k$

Comment: Getting the derivative in terms of $x,y$ isn’t bad.

Comment: Use implicit differentiation

Comment: @Empty2 Do you mean I should draw the curve by plotting points *OR* to use a parameter?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B%28x%5E5+%2B+y%5E5%29+%3D%3D+5+a%5E2+%28x+y%5E2%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+-15%2C+15%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-15%2C+15%7D%5D+for+a%3D5

Comment: One way would be to set x to a constant and solve for y. If this is done enough times, then one can find the basic graph shape and plot the points.

Comment: it makes sense in polar coordinates. The axes are directions where radius goes to zero, so flower petals. Next, along any ray there is at most one $r.$  It cannot all be flower petals as the asymptote plays a factor. Anyway, write in polar, find the limit of $r$ as $\theta$ approaches any of six rays, one calculation for either side, so twelve calculations.